# URL rewrite errors, possible overwriting?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am fairly new to .htaccess and its applications, here is a very straight forward question. I have the following rewrite rule in my .htaccess. The first RewriteRule replaces all .php in my file, and the second RewriteRule is to overwrite a question mark in a link into a slash, but I do not know why the second rule doesn't work. In my other PHP file that has the link to the "profile" link, the link to it is `<a href= "profile?'some id fetch from php'"`, the link works fine with the `?` in it, however even after I apply my second rule, nothing happens to it when I click on it. Is it possible that the first rule is somehow preventing the second one from occurring? Or is it because something goes wrong in my href link? The following is my .htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)$ profile?$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance for any feedback.
Ray

Comment: Sorry, please disregard the additional p in the second rewrite rule

Comment: You can [edit] the question to fix it.

Comment: yes thanks, I didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

Your first rewrite pattern accepts any characters in URI excluding a dot, so it also matches "/profile/123",

Change your regex pattern :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/?$ profile?$1 [L]
```

Comment: or change the order of rules.

Comment: hi guys, thanks you for the feedback,  I have tried both methods and play around a bit, but I still can't get that to work. Could it be the fact the the link is in my file is causing the problem?

Comment: Should I change the link into somehting else? It is currently for example <a href= "profile?106>, but if I changed to something like profile/106 or profile/106/, my 404 error page comes up